# how to check in python if file can be downloaded from http server

Tags: python, httpserver

i have two Artifactory servers AF1 & AF2 for my content,

AF1 is OPENID authenticated, AF2 is simple uid/pwd authenticated

i download files from AF2 using my python scripts, now i would like to know if the file exists, i can do that using simple function as below,

The problem i am facing is the url list is dynamic and changes to AF1 to AF2, but either of the cases the return code is 200 since the file exits in both server, i would like to know if there is way to know if the file can be downloaded or not before hand so that i can handle it

```
def check_file(url, uid, pwd):

    print 'checking ' + url 
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (uid, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)

    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            #print connection.getcode()
            #connection.close()
        return 0
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            #print e.getcode()
        return 1
```

Comment: have you tried sending a HEAD request for the file? The server should just return the headers without a body, and therefore a file.

Comment: could i do it say connection.getHEAD() ? also how does this confirm if the file can be downloaded or not, plz eloborate

Comment: hope you meant to add <request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'>

Comment: yes, get_method should return HEAD. If the file can be downloaded the server should return a 2xx status code. If it cannot it should return anything else. It does depend weather or not the Artifactory server is capable of handling HEAD requests, and returns correct status codes though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added extra clause to check the size of the file , and this fails for AF1 server as it just says file is present but doesn't give details of file attributes, could get this working through below changes

def check_file(url, uid, pwd):

```
print 'checking ' + url 
request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (uid, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'

try:
    connection = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        data = connection.info()
        connection.close()
    try:
        file_size = int(data.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
        return 0
    except  IndexError, e:
        return 1        
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
    return 1
```